# trouble with Eclipse compiler

Tags: c

I used Eclipse to compile c code, but all of a sudden all my codes got trouble, which were all correct previously.

for example if I want use scanf input a argument, before the scanf a printf statement I will use for guiding the user. like printf("type the size\n"); but after compiling in Console I need type the size first, then the printf("type the size\n") command just pop up, which should be the other way round.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void try(int a);

int main(void)
{
    int a;

    printf("type the size\n");
    try(a);

    return 0;
}

void try(int a)
{
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

the result:
2
type the size
size is chosen 2
I need type a number first, here like I need type 2 first and then the "type the size" just pop up.

here is what I want :

type the size
2
size is chosen 2

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler...

Comment: sorry I use Eclipse and MinGW GCC to code C

Comment: As an aside, `try(a)` isn't going to pass the entered value out of the function. You'd need to pass a pointer to a instead to have it written to in-place, or perhaps better just return `a` from the function and `a = try();`. Finally `try` is reserved word in C++ so it might be better to pick a different name.

Comment: How do you get `size is chosen` in the output ?

Comment: no no no, it's just a test not a real size readout code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a [bug in eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732) and this has been reported by most of the people using eclipse and MinGW.

To overcome this problem, you could use `fflush(stdout)` after every call to `printf` or use the following in the start of `main` :

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This will cause `stdout` and `stderr` to flush immediately whenever it is written to.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, for example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void try(int *a);
int main() {
 int a;
 printf("type the size\n");
 fflush(stdout);
 try(&a);
 return 0;
}
void try(int *a){
 scanf("%d", a);
 printf("%d\n", *a);
 fflush(stdout);
 return;
}
```

Also, you need to get the value set in atry back in main, so, you need to pass a a pointer as shown

Comment: This does not solve actual problem. After first `printf` buffer is not flushed before `scanf` from `try`. C standard clarifies that it should be flushed before first encountered `scanf`, so it's clearly a bug in Eclipse. One workaround is to force it by `fflush` standard function, as pointed by @CoolGuy.

Comment: Yes, you may use fflush(stdout) after every printf, edited my ans, accept?

Comment: Still wrong in your code. You have confused first `printf` (from `main`) with second one from `try`.